# Android: no error but failed to solve the null option at the end of line

Tags: java, android

Here is my code which takes a text from first text field in pashto but in english syntax and converts to pashto syntax by clicking the button, its running cool, but the problem is that when converts at the end it shows null at the end of each line and it also did not show the last character in pashto
And for the same program if you guys have some easy way then let me know.

Converted language

[image]

```
package aims.khan.trans;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnconvert;
    EditText txtconvertfrom, txtconvertto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnconvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnconvert);
        txtconvertfrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtconvertfrom);
        txtconvertto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtconvertto);

        btnconvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String a = Conversion();
                txtconvertto.setText(a);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String Conversion() {
        String a = null;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(" ", "\u0020");
        map.put("A", "\u0627");
        map.put("a", "\u0627");
        map.put("B", "\u0628");
        map.put("b", "\u0628");
        // map.put("C" , "\u0686");
        // map.put("c" , "\u0686");
        map.put("CH", "\u0686");
        map.put("ch", "\u0686");
        map.put("D", "\u062F");
        map.put("d", "\u062F");
        map.put("E", "\u064A");
        map.put("e", "\u064A");
        map.put("F", "\u0641");
        map.put("f", "\u0641");
        map.put("G", "\u06AB");
        map.put("g", "\u06AB");
        map.put("H", "\u062D");
        map.put("h", "\u062D");
        map.put("I", "\u064A");
        map.put("i", "\u064A");
        map.put("J", "\u062C");
        map.put("j", "\u062C");
        map.put("K", "\u0643");
        map.put("k", "\u0643");
        map.put("L", "\u0644");
        map.put("l", "\u0644");
        map.put("M", "\u0645");
        map.put("m", "\u0645");
        map.put("N", "\u0646");
        map.put("n", "\u0646");
        map.put("O", "\u0648");
        map.put("o", "\u0648");
        map.put("P", "\u0628");
        map.put("p", "\u0628");
        map.put("Q", "\u0642");
        map.put("q", "\u0642");
        map.put("R", "\u0631");
        map.put("r", "\u0631");
        map.put("S", "\u0633");
        map.put("s", "\u0633");
        map.put("sh", "\u0634");
        map.put("T", "\u062A");
        map.put("t", "\u062A");
        map.put("U", "\u0648");
        map.put("u", "\u0648");
        map.put("V", "\u0648");
        map.put("v", "\u0648");
        map.put("W", "\u0648");
        map.put("w", "\u0648");
        map.put("X", "\u0633");
        map.put("x", "\u0633");
        map.put("Y", "\u064A");
        map.put("y", "\u064A");
        map.put("Z", "\u0632");
        map.put("z", "\u0632");
        map.put("TH", "\u062A");
        map.put("th", "\u062A");
        String convert = txtconvertfrom.getText().toString();
        char[] convert2 = convert.toCharArray();

        if (convert2.length <= 1) {

            a += map.get(String.valueOf(convert2));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < convert2.length - 1; i++) {

                switch (convert2[i]) {
                case 'c':
                    switch (convert2[i + 1]) {
                    case 'h':
                        a += map.get(String.valueOf("ch"));
                        i++;
                        continue;
                    case 'k':
                        a += map.get(String.valueOf("k"));
                        i++;
                        continue;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                case 's':
                    switch (convert2[i + 1]) {
                    case 'h':
                        a += map.get(String.valueOf("sh"));
                        i++;
                        continue;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    a += map.get(String.valueOf(convert2[i]));
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: To improve performance: it is sufficient to declare the **map** as a member (= global) variable `static final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` and then initialize it once, e.g. in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

`String` a = null;

Change to

`String` a = "";

And try